# How do I read and fix backtrace error on TB-LMTO calculation

Tags: backtrace

When performing a electronic structure calculation I get this error after imputting the a lattice paramter:
'Error termination. Backtrace:'
'#0  0x7fd8bed11d5a'
'#1  0x7fd8bed12869'
'#2  0x7fd8bed1354f'
'#3  0x7fd8bef49061'
'#4  0x7fd8bef4929e'
'#5  0x7fd8bef5a1e7'
'#6  0x555b2cd0bd3f'
'#7  0x555b2cd09ef'

How do I fix it?

I tried other space groups to see if the error was with specific space group or if it was the entire monoclinic unit cell. I also did a calculation using a different crystal structure and it worked fine.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.